# How does positioning work in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a drag-and-drop engine in JavaScript. Right now, I'm adding a bounds feature which will trap the `.drag` object inside its parent element. However, to do this, I need to understand how positioning works in html, and I don't. Can anyone thoroughly explain it?

Javascript Engine:

```
// JavaScript Document

var posX;
var posY;
var element;
var currentPos;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", drag, false);

function drag(event) {
    if(~event.target.className.search(/drag/)) {
        element = event.target;
        element.style.zIndex="100";
        currentPos = findPos(element);
        posX = event.clientX -currentPos.x;
        posY = event.clientY -currentPos.y;
            if(~event.target.className.search(/bound/))
                document.addEventListener("mousemove", boundMovement, false);
            else
                document.addEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    }
}

function freeMovement(event) { // This functions works

    if (typeof(element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly

    element.style.left = event.clientX - posX + "px";
    element.style.top = event.clientY - posY + "px";
}

function boundMovement(event) { // This function doesn't work

    if (typeof(element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly

    // Below logic is false- I wish to understand why =]
    currentPos = findPos(element.offsetParent);
    if((event.clientX - posX) <= currentPos.x)
        element.style.left = event.clientX - posX + "px";
    if((event.clientY - posY) <= currentPos.y)
        element.style.top = event.clientY - posY + "px";
}

function drop() {
    element.style.zIndex="1";
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", boundMovement, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //alert("DEBUG_DROP");
}

function findPos(obj) { // Donated by `lwburk` on StackOverflow
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.drag {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.bound {
    /* Class to signify that the drag_object can not leave the parent element */
    ;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor:move;
}

p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline-style: dotted;
    outline-color: #000;
    outline-width: 1px;
}
```

Some example HTML:

```
<p class="drag bound square">Thing One</p>
<p class="drag square">Thing Two</p>
```

Please note I am including the JavaScript so that if I have questions on how things are applied relative to what I've written. Also, thank you all for reading and helping. StackOverflow has been an exceptional resource in learning how to code in JavaScript.

EDIT:

1) I should say that I am coding the engine to help me learn the language. This is my first week of JavaScript, and I would like to be able to code in the language before I use a library.

2) For example I would really like for someone to explain how offsets are working here. I would like to know how instead of using `position:absolute` to make my JavaScript engine, I can use `position:relative` so that elements can stack on top of each other ect.

Comment: I highly recommend using jQuery UI for drag and drop. It will save you many hours of cross-browser testing.

Comment: @Mark, I appreciate the suggestion, but this is my first week of Javascript. I am doing this to help me learn the language. I would like to learn the language before I start using libraries for shortcuts. Sometimes you need to re-invent the wheel to understand how the wheel works ;p

Comment: kudos for writing from scratch! I've reworked your code a bit, and posted on jsfiddle. I'm going to add more explanation to my answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted a solution at http://jsfiddle.net/vJ6r6/.

First of all, I nested the items to be dragged inside the bounding box:

```
<div class="bound">Thing One
    <div class="drag square">Thing Two</div>
    <div class="drag square">Thing Three</div>
</div>
```

Also, I turned them into div's because p's can't be nested. (Don't forget to change the style declaration as well.)

Then, I set styles on the bounding box:

```
<style>
.bound {
    margin: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

The key property is `position: relative`, which causes the items inside it to be positioned relative to it, rather than to the page. **Note that because I'm using relative positioning, this example works best when you want to keep the items in a particular container.**

My changes to the JavaScript were more radical, so here's the whole thing:

```
<script>
var dragInfo;

function down(event) {
    if (~event.target.className.search(/drag/)) {
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
        var t = event.target;
        t.style.zIndex = 100;
        dragInfo = {
            element: t,
            // record the bounds
            maxX: t.parentNode.offsetWidth - t.offsetWidth,
            maxY: t.parentNode.offsetHeight - t.offsetHeight,
            // we don't need findPos, because it's no longer relative to the page
            posX: event.clientX - t.offsetLeft,
            posY: event.clientY - t.offsetTop
        };
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    }
}

function freeMovement(event) {
    // the min and max calculations keep the X and Y within the bounds
    dragInfo.element.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientX - dragInfo.posX, dragInfo.maxX)) + "px";
    dragInfo.element.style.top = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientY - dragInfo.posY, dragInfo.maxY)) + "px";
}

function drop() {
    dragInfo.element.style.zIndex = 1;
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);
</script>
```

Note that this line:

```
dragInfo.element.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientX - dragInfo.posX, dragInfo.maxX)) + 'px';
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
var x = event.clientX - dragInfo.posX;
if (x < 0) x = 0;
if (x > dragInfo.maxX) x = dragInfo.maxX;
dragInfo.element.style.left = x + 'px';
```

Comment: I played around and found a bug ;p ! http://jsfiddle.net/vJ6r6/2/  And I'm going to need a bit of an explanation indeed. There are a lot of changes =/

Comment: @Dbz You have to put the items to be dragged inside of the bounding box. I've edited my answer to include more explanation. Comment again if you have questions.

Comment: @Mark, first off, thanks for explaining why I don't need `findPos()`, it was driving me nuts. Second, is making it necessary to have a `.bound` box a good idea? It seems like a limitation rather than a feature (although it clearly has its upsides). And, I'm going to look up the JavaScript math functions so I understand how they work before asking about how the (math side of the) bounding works.

Comment: Requiring a bound box does make the JavaScript simpler. If you needed a truly generalized, all-purpose solution, you would need to write tons more code (like jQuery UI...). I'm going to edit my answer now to explain the Math bit.

Comment: @Mark, great. I think I understand the math now. And yes, seeing as I am learning- I am attempting to (step by step) make a truly-generalized/all-purpose solution. To get rid of the required bounding box, will I need to make two movement functions like I had previously?

Comment: I would also have to change the `dragInfo` object to use my old `findPos()` function because it might not be in a `position:relative` container.

Comment: You will not need two movement functions. However, you will need findPos() - you'll have to run it both for the item being dragged and for the bound box. You'll want a minX and minY (not just 0), and you'll have to do the calculations differently. You'll probably also want a better way to find elements in the DOM (like searching by class name).

Comment: @Mark, can you explain (give an example vs. what I did) what you mean by a better way to find elements in the DOM?

Comment: What I'm talking about is a good function like GetElementsByClassName. Just pass it a class name like "drag" and it finds all the elements having that class. The reason you'd want to do that is so that you can apply your mousedown event directly to draggable items, and not to the whole document. You can find many implementations of GetElementsByClassName on the Internet, or you can just write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem (with your example at least) is that when you call the `findPos` function for the bounded element in `boundMovement`, you are passing its parent, which has no parent of its own. So inside the `findPos` function this specific line

```
if (obj.offsetParent) {
    // ...
```

is returning undefined because it doesn't have a parent. Try removing that if statement and try it again.

Comment: No, it's working like it should. The function `freeMovement()` uses it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Dbz, interesting. I don't see a call to `findPos` in `freeMovement`. In any case, here is a jsFiddle with your code and some modification: http://jsfiddle.net/sSFbK/

Comment: So, I added some stuff to your modification, but it doesn't quite work: http://jsfiddle.net/sSFbK/2/

Comment: @Dbz, one thing first: an absolutely positioned element's offset parent is the first parent (or parent of parent, or...) that has a position other than static. So that div is not its offset parent because the default position is static. See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: @ZDYN, Oh boy, that's frustrating. Does that mean my `findPos()` function will only work with `position: absolute` elements?

Comment: @Dbz, no it just means you have to give the parent `position: absolute` or `position: relative` in CSS.

Comment: @Dbz, here's another update on that jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sSFbK/3/. Specifically I added `position: relative` to the `div` parent of the `p` element. Also made some modifications to the if statements in `boundMovement`.

Comment: @ZDYN, very interesting. I'm glad the math there works out. I'm having second thoughts on how I structured the "bounding" scheme though. I like how Mark's version has the bound belong to one of the parenting `div`s. Seems like a better idea in the long run. Thank you for all of help making my version work =]

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful
[A list Apart's css-positioning 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)

What exactly is the problem you are having?

Absolute removes the element from normal "flow of the document" and allows you to position it where you want.

Relative position is a lot like static but allows you to absolute position elements within it.

Static follows the normal document flow. (stacking)

By the way, I recommend you use a library or framework like JQuery or Prototype instead of building this by hand. It will save you hours of frustration and testing in different browsers.

Edit:
Since you are hellbent doing this the hard way...I hope I can be of some help.
I recomend you download the the firebug addon for Firefox if that is what you use or get familiar Javascript Console under tools in Chrome.

HTML

```
<p class="drag bound square">Thing One</p>
<p class="drag square">Thing Two</p>
```

There is no parent/child relationship here did you mean for the document to be the boundry?
freeMovement does not call findPos on the elements offSetParent where BoundMovement does.
This is retuning undefined since the document does not have that property.

Try wrapping these two paragraphs in something other than the body tag.

```
<div id='container'>
<p class="drag bound square">Thing One</p>
<p class="drag square">Thing Two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I will definitely read that web-page, thanks. My exact issue is that I can't figure out how to make the boundMovement() function work in my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this jQuery demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

using jQuery makes JavaScript much easier, and will also ensure that your code works cross browser.

Comment: Yes, but as I said in the original post and in several comments: I do not wish to use jQuery before I actually learn JavaScript. I do, however, appreciate the suggestion =]

Comment: sorry I did not see that, on a side note to "elements can stack on top of each other" is not related to position. To change their stacking order use CSS  z-index

Comment: Static "elements can stack on top of each other" was a poor choice of words. I meant that static elements, are listed vertically down the page the first appearing above/before the second.